# Python numpy : постановка условия при работе с массивами

Tags: python, массивы, циклы, numpy

Есть вопрос по коду:

```
f = [0.1,1,1.5]
f = map(np.array,[f])
new = (f[:,None] - f[:])
print(new)
```

Результат:

```
[[ 0.  -0.9 -1.4]
 [ 0.9  0.  -0.5]
 [ 1.4  0.5  0. ]]
```

Легко видеть, что нули - это результат вычитания числа из самого себя.
Вопрос: можно ли в этом коде задать условие, чтобы число не вычиталось само из себя (то есть чтобы при условии i = i подсчет не проводился) чтобы вышло вот так:

```
[[-0.9 -1.4]
 [ 0.9 -0.5]
 [ 1.4  0.5 ]]
```

Интересно было бы узнать, как это можно реализовать обычным генератором с привязкой к номеру элемента в листе (чтобы при условии i = i подсчет не проводился).

Comment: вам нужно от элемента n отнять все последующие кроме него самого?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: я тоже не вижу отличия от вашего предыдущего вопроса... Что вас не устраивает в ответах на ваш предыдущий вопрос?